# Проблема с запуском телеграмм бота на Python

Tags: python, pycharm, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет, я решил первый раз попробовать написать бота для телеграмма, сам изучаю cpp, но на python писать удобнее, поэтому начал на нем. Пишу в приложении PyCharm.

Проблема заключается в том, что сам бот не работает и не реагирует на команды. Я добавил вывод логов, но они тоже пустые. Можете пожалуйста подсказать проблема в самом коде или это у меня что-то с провайдером может быть. Библиотеку если что добавил `pip install python-telegram-bot`. Ошибок при запуске не выдает.

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import logging

bot_token = "токен не хочу палить"
bot - telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def start(update, context):
    logger.info('Бот получил команду /start')
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Привет! Я твой личный рецепт-бот. Чтобы получить рецепт блюда, просто введи его название)"),

recipes = {
    "пицца": "Рецепт приготовления пиццы...",
    "паста": "Рецепт приготовления пасты...",
    # Добавьте свои рецепты здесь
}

def get_recipe(update, context):
    dish = " ".join(context.args).lower()
    if dish in recipes:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=recipes[dish])
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text= "Рецепта такого нет")

updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("getrecipe", get_recipe))

updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с [официальными примерами](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/latest/examples.html) вот исправленный код:

```py
import logging

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Application

bot_token = "ТОКЕН"

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def start(update, context):
    logger.info('Бот получил команду /start')
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                   text="Привет! Я твой личный рецепт-бот. Чтобы получить рецепт блюда, просто введи "
                                        "его название)"),


recipes = {
    "пицца": "Рецепт приготовления пиццы...",
    "паста": "Рецепт приготовления пасты...",
    # Добавьте свои рецепты здесь
}


async def get_recipe(update, context):
    dish = " ".join(context.args).lower()
    if dish in recipes:
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=recipes[dish])
    else:
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Рецепта такого нет")


application = Application.builder().token(bot_token).build()
application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
application.add_handler(CommandHandler("getrecipe", get_recipe))

application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
```

Comment: Изменил свой код на этот, запустил, но всё равно бот не работает

Comment: @tishetishe какая версия python-telegram-bot и python установлена добавьте `import telegram` и `print(telegram.__version__)` в начало кода.